# Ruby Argument Error with named parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider the following Ruby Code:

```
def f1(p1, p2: nil, p3: nil)
  puts "Parameter 1: #{p1}"
  puts "Parameter 2: #{p2}"
  puts "Parameter 3: #{p3}"
end

def f2(p1, p2: nil, p3: nil)
  f1(p1, p2, p3)   
end

# This will throw error ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
f2("Hi")
```

In the above code, my problem is I need to list the parameters in both f1 and f2 (user requirement). At the same time I should enable the named parameters for the user (because the 3 parameters can become 30 parameters with most of them having a default value)

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used named parameters, you have to specify them explicitly.

```
...
def f2(p1, p2: nil, p3: nil)
  f1(p1, p2: p2, p3: p3)   # specify p2 and p3
end

f2("Hi")
```

When you call `f1` you have to specify explicitly `p2` and `p3` if you want to define them

Check the [official documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) or some [third-party resources](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) about this

```
def foo(arg1 = 1, arg2:, arg3: nil)
   puts "#{arg1} #{arg2} #{arg3}"
end

foo(arg2: 'arg2')
# Will display
# 1 arg2

foo('arg1_defined', arg2: 'arg2')
# WIll display
# arg1_defined arg2
```

Note: Also named arguments do not have to follow order, you can place them at any order you want, but after other arguments

```
foo(arg3: 'arg3_with_value', arg2: 'arg2_val')
# 1 arg2_val arg3_with_value

foo(arg3: 'arg3_val', 10)
# SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting =>
# they have to be after not-named arguments
```